# Unexpected result in deleting DataGridView Columns

Tags: c#

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("col2");
        dt.Columns.Add("col3");
        dt.Columns.Add("col4");
        dt.Columns.Add("col5");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
        dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
        dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

In this program, I created a DataTable with 5 columns. This will be the DataSource of the DataGridView. Some columns in the DataTable doesn't need to be seen by the user, but will be used by the program later on.

After the last line, the columns are arranged as : col2, col5, col1, col3, col4. Why does it appear like this? Shouldn't it be removed from the DataGridView? What should I do to make it appear as "col2, col5"?

EDIT: I want to *remove* some Columns from the DataGridView, yet still be available in the DataTable. Also, it works inside an event (like Button_Click)

EDIT: I **still** haven't figured out why this is happening. I have no choice but to create another thread (BackgroundWorker) to do this...

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int i;
        dataGridView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("col3");
            dt.Columns.Add("col4");
            dt.Columns.Add("col5");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(2);
            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        });
    }
```

As far as I can tell, Haris Hasan was right; that the Form containing the DataGridView should appear at least once. But I'm still confused why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to display DataGridView once before you can remove any column. Try this by displaying DataGridView one time and then delete the columns and see what happens

Comment: I did that earlier. I put the code where I remove the columns in a button event, and those columns were removed when I clicked the button. Why is that not happening when the removal of columns is below the "dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;"?

Comment: I don't know the details why exactly this is happening but I know this happens. What you can do is something like handle an event which raises as soon as the DataGridView is displayed and in that event remove the columns

Comment: @Gerald Sorry I really confused...! are you saying that `RemoveAt` is not removing the column?

Comment: I used this code in a method that is called in the BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted event, and it works. The same method doesn't work properly when inside the constructor of the form... Can I throw an event in the Backgroundworker RunWorkerCompleted if RunWorkerAsync() is not called?

Comment: @Knvn, Yes! And I have no idea why! Apparently, it does remove the column if it is removed when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkfe535h.aspx)** property of the **DataGridView** to order the columns. In order to hide a column you can set false to the **Visible** property of a particular column.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnTobeHided"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: But this is what is used to change the arrangements of the Columns. I don't want those other columns to be displayed. I used RemoveAt(), but it didn't remove them. Those columns that 'should' be deleted were just moved at the end of the dataGridView1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the columns you could try setting their visibility...

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: It is still "col1" if I do MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name);. 

I have used the RemoveAt() on the other part of my program. The only difference between the two is that I used another thread to store values in the DataTable. After that, I did the same as the one above. Strangely, that one worked.

Comment: When you run `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name);` it will be `col1` only because you are just changing the visibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want columns in the grid for all of the columns in the table, set datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns to false before binding the datatable to the datasource.  Then create and bind the datagridview columns you actually want to have.

AutoGenerateColumns defaults to true, and yet it very seldom gives us what we really want.  Take the time to build your datagridview columns exactly as you want and don't trust the default processing.

Comment: I don't want *all* of the columns, but I only want *some* of them to appear on the DataGridView. And by 'appear', I mean having those columns removed from there, not just hide them...

Comment: If you set AutoGenerateColmuns to false, you won't get any columns by default.  You can then add code to create the specific columns you want.  AutoGenerateColumns = true creates a DGV column for every column in the DataTable, which is not what you wnated